# How to create a local central repository for maven artifacts

Tags: maven, repository

My organization uses maven for all our projects. Every time we create new maven project, the artifacts are downloaded from maven central repository. But i want to create organization level local repository where all the maven artifacts are available and when new maven project created should look for the artifact in local repository and if not found, then only look in the maven central repository. Can anyone let me know how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: You should definitely install a repository manager as the answers suggest; Nexus is free and easy to set up. You will save a lot of time and bandwidth not going to central for every single artifact.

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at [Sonatype Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) repository manager. It can be used as a proxy to cache remote repositories. After Nexus has been set up, you will just have to edit your `settings.xml` and add something like this:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>nexus-proxy</id>
    <name>Nexus Proxy</name>
    <url>http://nexus.example.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php) or a similar [Repository Management](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) tool